# The performance difference between a command that does the same thing

Tags: shell, debian, performance

What is the difference? 
It is performed in the same?

```
tar -czf files/compressed/gzip/archive.tar.gz -C files/original .

tar -c -C files/original . | gzip -1 > files/compressed/gzip/archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Your title asks about performance difference - did you measure the performance to see what happens in the real world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the former, the implementation of tar uses a gzip library to perform the compression itself.  In the latter the output of tar gets piped into a separate executable that performs the compression.  The former is probably slightly more efficient as it doesn't involve extra system calls to write/read the data to/from the pipe, but a human would likely not notice the difference.

Comment: At least GNU tar will call `gzip` itself, I don't think `tar` pipe to `gzip` is slower `tar` itself in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Let's do some tests.

`tar` alone:

```
time sh -c 'tar -czf test.tar.gz ~/Downloads'
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
=====
JOB sh -c 'tar -czf test.tar.gz ~/Downloads'
74%    cpu
30.02s real
20.64s user
1.82s sys
```

`tar` pipe to `gzip`:

```
time sh -c 'tar -c ~/Downloads | gzip -1 > test.tar.gz'
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
=====
JOB sh -c 'tar -c ~/Downloads | gzip -1 > test.tar.gz'
65%    cpu
27.23s real
16.07s user
1.88s sys
```

It seems reasonable to me that the `tar` pipe to `gzip` can be faster because they were run in parallel in multiple core machine (mine has 2 CPUs).

Comment: Did you run both of these with a warm cache?

Comment: I ran the same test with a warm cache, compressing from ramdisk to ramdisk, and found no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

In the second option there are 2 applications that need to be started (`tar` and `gzip`). This takes extra time. Also the piping takes extra resources. This results in a longer execution time.

Comment: That's not necessarily true if tar and gzip are not running on the same CPU. But anyway the difference is likely to be microscopic in real-world scenarios.

Comment: I don't know how the shell handles the starting of gzip. Does it start gzip at the same time as tar or does it 'wait' until tar generates some output? But I agree with you that the difference in the start-up is very small in all cases. Not noticeable for the human eye. Think that the piping will cost more.